# Calculate average in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to calculate the class average of a class where students can hold different amounts of subjects (e.g.: two students in a class of which one takes 3 subjects and the other 2). How do I get the class average that applies to all students? I already have their total term score in a table. I know the formula for calculating the average is simply the total averages of individual students divided by the number of students, but I can't seem to get it working. Can anyone please help me write a query that will calculate and print out this class average?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT student_id, SUM(CA_total)/count(term_total) AS average
FROM score_entry
GROUP BY student_id
```

HERE IS THE OUTCOME. [result from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqKWp.jpg)

BUT I want the final result to be the sum of 25 + 26.5 which will be 51.5 then divided by the 2 students in the class should give 25.75. this is the class average. I want the query or code that will echo out the final answer 25.75. thanks

Comment: Please add some code which you have already tried.

Comment: @ SeekAndDestroy. I have edited my question appropriately.

Comment: And have answered it since.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for SQL AVG function. More about it here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_avg.asp

Comment: pls can someone help me out with the above question ?